# nlohmann json: Why am I getting a parse error?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I'm really confused why I'm getting a parse error when I'm trying to parse a file in C++ using the nlohmann library.

My code is exactly the same as one I copied from their GitHub page:

```cpp
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    ifstream ifs("test.json");

    if (nlohmann::json::accept(ifs))
        cout << "accepted" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not accepted" << endl;

    json j = json::parse(ifs);
}
```

And the JSON file is just this:

```json
{ 
   "test": 5
}
```

For some reason, this throws an error when I get to the `parse()` function, despite the `accept()` function returning true, which means the JSON was accepted as valid.

Also, when I do something like this:

```cpp
json j = json::parse(R"({"test": "aaa"})");
```

That works fine. But I can't parse the `ifstream` object.

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be the issue here?

I have no ideas, and I'm clueless, because it seems I did everything right.

Comment: "Unhandled exception at 0x75A2D902 in MapStudy.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::parse_error at memory location 0x00DDE658."

Comment: I fixed it, I didnt realize the accept function reads through the file so then it has to be reset again for the parse function. Or don't use accept before parse without resetting the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once `nlohmann::json::accept` has returned, the stream `ifs` has been consumed.

When you later `json::parse(ifs)`, you try to parse what is essentially an empty file, and an empty string is not a valid json document.

You need to rewind the stream or reopen your file.

```
// rewind
ifs.clear();
ifs.seekg(0);
json j = json::parse(ifs);

// reopen
json j = json::parse(std::ifstream{"test.json"});
```